# Utilizar <link rel=preload> en mi site en WordPress + Google PageSpeed Tools

Tags: wordpress, optimización, googlepagespeed

`Buenos días`, estoy intentando solucionar el siguiente error que me aparece en Google PageSpeed Tools:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo acceder al archivo correspondiente y escribir el `<link rel=preload>`.
He intentado utilizar plugins y no hay manera ...

Por lo que he podido saber, el segundo error, el de la fuente `fa-regular-400.woff2`, es debido a la fuente del reCaptcha de un plugin de formularios, he intentando cambiar la versión del reCaptcha y al parecer se me quitó el error, pero ahora ha vuelto ...

No sé si Google PageSpeed Tools funcionará bien porqué a veces sale una cosa y a veces otra.

A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable porqué llevo una semana intentando eliminar este error.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

PD: La web en cuestión es https://euro-sur.com/.

EDIT: Cabe destacar que esos errores solo me los marca en móvil, es decir, en análisis en PC no me muestra ninguno de estos errores.

Comment: Si miras el código fuente tienes puestas las lineas pero comentadas. Parece ser algo del Elementor. Comprueba que no tengas alguna opción desactivada. Sino, aquí tienes como añadirlo a mano: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/343581/how-to-add-an-html-rel-preload-tag-to-the-header

Comment: Sii, intenté hacer la llama a unos archivos en el header pero no funcionó ...
Voy a intentar hacer lo que pone en el link que me has pasado, gracias por respondes!

Comment: Sino edita manualmente el header.php de tu plantilla y alli podras poner manualmente las etiquetas.

Comment: Es que no me queda muy claro qué tengo que poner en el header, es decir, la ruta que poner, ¿me explico? ¿Esto? --> ```<link rel="preload" href=" /fa-regular-400.woff2"> ```

Comment: <link rel="preload" href="h t t p://dominio.com/wp-content/ruta-al-tema/fa-regular-400.woff2" as="font">

Comment: segun el source hay varios plugins levantando esa fuente (font awesome 5.x), y varias versiones por lo que se ve, asi que para la url del font tenes al menos 3 para elegir